# Oracle SQL - Sum up and show text if > 0

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm totally new with Oracle SQL and my question may seem stupid but I have some difficulties to solve my problem.

Current situation:
I have following tables: **Supplier, Debtor, Invoice**

Every **Supplier** has various **Debtors** and every **Debtor** has various **Invoices**. 
I want to create an evaluation which shows me the following scenario:

A list of all **Debtors** from a **Supplier**. I also want to see in that list if the **Debtor** once haven't payed his invoice. I have this information within the table Invoice as the attribute called "payed" and possible values are 0 (payed) and 1 (not payed). I just want to see the debtor ONCE in the list so if there is only ONE invoice which is 1, it should show me "1" or "Not Payed" in the list. Right now when a debtor has 100 invoices it shows me 100 times the debtor with the info "0" or "1".

Currently:

```
     SELECT company.company_id,   
         company.companyname_1,   
         supplier.supplier_id,   
         supplier.suppliername_1,   
         debtor.debtor_id_from_supplier,   
         debtor_ext.debtorname_1,   
         debtor_ext.street,   
         debtor_ext.street_number,   
         debtor_ext.postcode,   
         debtor_ext.city,   
         debtor.approved_limit,   
         debitor.limit_left,   
         debitor.limit_status,   
         debitor.limit_type,   
         debitor.prosecution,
         CASE
            WHEN invoice.payed = 0 THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
         END as deb_payment
    FROM debtor, 
         debtor_ext,   
         company,   
         supplier,
         invoice
   WHERE ( company.company_id = supplier.company_id ) and  
         ( supplier.supplier_id = debtor.supplier_id ) and  
         ( debtor.debtor_id = debtor_ext.debtor_id ) and  
         ( debtor.supplier_id = invoice.supplier_id ) and  
         ( debtor.debtor_id_from_supplier = invoice.debtor_id_from_supplier )
```

**CODE CORRECTED!** 
Hope you guys can help me

Comment: No join conditions?

Comment: Currently not. I tried LEFT JOIN but somehow it showed the same amount of result

Comment: Add some sample table data and its expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: You should provide some key attributes in each of those tables.

Comment: So, if there are 100 invoice for a Debtor and there is at least one invoice in `not paid` then it should show `1` else `0`.Am I right?

Comment: To start with: you are joining all tables with an out-dated syntax (the comma). In current syntax this would be `FROM supplier CROSS JOIN debtor CROSS JOIN invoice`. So you are combining all suppliers with all debtors with all invoices and create a result set of completely unrelated data. You say a supplier has various debtors, so we'd expect a relation; something like `FROM supplier INNER JOIN debtor ON debtor.supplier_id = supplier.supplier_id`.

Comment: Thanks for your tip Thorsten. It was my mistake just to paste a part of the code. Can you please read my question again. I updated the code which is now the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, In your query, you're doing `cross join` which is not required and also affects on the performance. I'll advice you to use `Inner Join` here.

Also,as the schema is not provided in question,I am giving solution for the below schema:

**Supplier:**

```
Supplier_Id (PK) | Supplier_Name
```

**Debtor:**

```
Debtor_Id (PK) | Debtor_Name | Supplier_Id (FK)
```

**Invoice:**

```
Invoice_Id (PK) | Supplier_Id (FK) | Debtor_Id (FK) | Amount | Payed
```

**Query:**

```
Select company.company_id,   
        company.companyname_1,   
        s.supplier_id,   
        s.suppliername_1,   
        d.debtor_id_from_supplier,   
        d.debtorname_1,   
        d.street,   
        d.street_number,   
        d.postcode,   
        d.city,   
        d.approved_limit,   
        d.limit_left,   
        d.limit_status,   
        d.limit_type,   
        d.prosecution,
        tmp.deb_payment
 From
 (
 SELECT d.supplier_id,
        d.debtor_id,           
    (
     CASE
        WHEN min(i.payed) <> max(i.payed) Then 'Not Payed'
        ELSE 'Payed'
     END
    )as deb_payment
FROM supplier s
inner join debtor d
on s.supplier_id = d.supplier_id
inner join invoice i
on i.supplier_id = d.supplier_id
and i.debtor_id = d.debtor_id
Group by d.supplier_id,d.debtor_id
) tmp
inner join supplier s    
on s.supplier_id = tmp.supplier_id
inner join company
on company.company_id = s.company_id   
inner join debtor d
on s.supplier_id = d.supplier_id
inner join debtor_ext de
d.debtor_id = de.debtor_id
;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your support Harshil. I made a mistake with just pasting a part of my Syntax. Can you have a look at my description at the top again? I pasted the whole sql code now.

Comment: You just gave the alias "d." to the table "debtor" AND "debtor_ext". Please keep in mind that these are 2 different tables

Comment: I know those are 2 different tables. And alias for `debtor_ext` is `de` not `d`

Comment: Are u getting any results? Or you getting some error?